# Not receiving message from producer using ActiveMQ VM Transport

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am using activeMQ **tcp//localhost** URL for quiet some time now and i don't have a problem with it. Currently, I am trying to use a "**vm//localhost**" connector, but i am having a problem with receiving a message from the producer. I am using spring boot, producer and consumer are in different jars. My consumer is receiving a null message. Am I missing something? Below is my code (taken form apache website). Thanks in advance

Producer.jar

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

String text = "Hello world! From: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + this.hashCode();
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

System.out.println("Sent message: " + message.hashCode() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
producer.send(message);

session.close();
connection.close();
```

Consumer.jar

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

connection.setExceptionListener(this);

Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);

// Wait for a message
Message message = consumer.receive(10000);

if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
    TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
    String text = textMessage.getText();
    System.out.println("Received 1: " + text);
} else {
    System.out.println("Received 2: " + message);
}

consumer.close();
session.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: Can you post the code that starts the consumer and the producer?
Are you sure that the producer sends messages before the consumer starts?

Comment: @HassenBennour codes are being run via SpringBootApplication CommandLineRunner. I've set the timeout time of the consumer to 10 seconds. Then i am executing the jar within that period. I also tried the otherway around but still no msg was received. According to println of my producer. the msg was sent. no exception was caught.

Comment: as i understood the consumer and producer are in different jar's but on the same SpringBootApplication and same JVM right ?

Comment: @HassenBennour unfortunately they are on different SpringBootApplication which means different JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was sure, vm is the transport inside the VM! and not accessible outside it, so the solution is that one of the 2 clients need to use vm transport and the other one tcp and ActiveMQ started in the one using vm transport or to embedd your 2 components in the same VM .

see my another answer for the same use case
 [How to send Jms message from one spring-boot application to another when both apps use embedded activemq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369023/how-to-send-jms-message-from-one-spring-boot-application-to-another-when-both-ap/41370319#41370319)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Your answer in the link is very helpful. i will try to implement it in my test case. My Manager is a C programmer so i need to defend that ActiveMQ (JMS) is fast enough for multi tier application.